# Query to duplicate rows and shift dates

Tags: sql

I have a data table that provides component-level forecasted product sales for the next 52 weeks. Each row provides data for a specific component-type that will be delivered in a finished assembly on a specific date. I am using this to create a financial model of our supply chain.

The query I use for a one-year forecast is quite straightforward:

```
Select
delivery_date,
component_type,
qty,
[other columns]
from [Table]
```

I then add some columns in excel to calculate dollar amounts and some other key dates based on a set of offline assumptions.

I now need to extrapolate several forward years based on the one-year forecast. To do this, I would like to adjust my query to do the following:

1. Repeat all rows in the initial output three times, but with exactly one, two and three years added to each original delivery_date. I.e., if the table has a row with a delivery_date of 2024-01-01, I would like to generate three additional identical rows, but with delivery_date of 2025-01-01, 2026-01-01, 2027-01-01
2. For each row, I would like to label the forecast year. Thus, a row for the current year forecast with delivery_date 2024-01-01 would be labeled year '0', the identical row with 2025-01-01 would be labeled year '1', 2026-01-01 would be year '2', etc.

My SQL skills are pretty basic. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up some example data:

```
create table #Table
(
    delivery_date date,
    component_type nvarchar(10),
    qty int
)

insert into #Table values
('2024-01-01','TypeA',100),
('2024-01-01','TypeB',5),
('2024-01-01','TypeC',6000),
('2024-02-01','TypeA',110),
('2024-02-01','TypeB',8),
('2024-02-01','TypeC',7000),
('2024-03-01','TypeA',97),
('2024-03-01','TypeB',2),
('2024-03-01','TypeC',4500)
```

Adding a column to hold our new "year number" value and populating it for the existing (2024) records:

```
alter table #Table add yearNum int
update #Table set yearNum = 0
```

Set up a loop to duplicate the existing "Year 0" records, but incrementing the dates and "year number" accordingly:

```
declare @yearsToForecast int = 5 -- Set this to the number of years into the future you want to duplicate for.
declare @currentYear int = 1

while (@currentYear <= @yearsToForecast)
begin
    insert into #Table
    select 
        dateadd(year,@currentYear,delivery_date), 
        component_type, 
        qty, 
        @currentYear 
    from #Table 
    where yearNum = 0

    set @currentYear = @currentYear + 1
end

select * from #Table

drop table #Table
```

This example gives the following output:

```
+---------------+----------------+------+---------+
| delivery_date | component_type | qty  | yearNum |
+---------------+----------------+------+---------+
| 2024-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       0 |
| 2024-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       0 |
| 2024-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       0 |
| 2024-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       0 |
| 2024-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       0 |
| 2024-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       0 |
| 2024-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       0 |
| 2024-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       0 |
| 2024-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       0 |
| 2025-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       1 |
| 2025-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       1 |
| 2025-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       1 |
| 2025-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       1 |
| 2025-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       1 |
| 2025-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       1 |
| 2025-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       1 |
| 2025-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       1 |
| 2025-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       1 |
| 2026-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       2 |
| 2026-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       2 |
| 2026-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       2 |
| 2026-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       2 |
| 2026-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       2 |
| 2026-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       2 |
| 2026-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       2 |
| 2026-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       2 |
| 2026-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       2 |
| 2027-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       3 |
| 2027-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       3 |
| 2027-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       3 |
| 2027-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       3 |
| 2027-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       3 |
| 2027-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       3 |
| 2027-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       3 |
| 2027-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       3 |
| 2027-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       3 |
| 2028-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       4 |
| 2028-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       4 |
| 2028-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       4 |
| 2028-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       4 |
| 2028-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       4 |
| 2028-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       4 |
| 2028-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       4 |
| 2028-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       4 |
| 2028-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       4 |
| 2029-01-01    | TypeA          |  100 |       5 |
| 2029-01-01    | TypeB          |    5 |       5 |
| 2029-01-01    | TypeC          | 6000 |       5 |
| 2029-02-01    | TypeA          |  110 |       5 |
| 2029-02-01    | TypeB          |    8 |       5 |
| 2029-02-01    | TypeC          | 7000 |       5 |
| 2029-03-01    | TypeA          |   97 |       5 |
| 2029-03-01    | TypeB          |    2 |       5 |
| 2029-03-01    | TypeC          | 4500 |       5 |
+---------------+----------------+------+---------+
```